# Opening google play store with Iframe

Tags: joomla

I have to integrate an external link(https://play.google.com/store) into my joomla site. I used an "iframe" to load the external link page (wrapper module) . But it does'nt open the site... does google restricts in displaying their play store site to be embedded?

Answer (score 0):

Is that your domain name have HTTPS security ?? If it's no the case, try your link with "http" instead of "https".

Some service has special way for to be embed in iframe. This way can be also prohibited. Check if this service bring an integration code.

Comment: Google doesnt allow their sites embed with iframe. is there any other way round that I can display their apps in my site

Comment: Maybe throw an Ajax request or CURL... but I'm pessimist.

Answer (score 0):

Certain links can be opened in iFrame using the [iframe-allow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iframe-allow/gifgpciglhhpmeefjdmlpboipkibhbjg?hl=en) to allow links.